# load multiple models in one

Tags: actionscript-3

had the task to load a single model that has a dozen small models - everything is fine - but it would be split into separate models for faster downloading, type model1, model2 ..., the question arose as can be written so that would not be repeated with the code

```
var mc1:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
mc1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
mc1.load(new URLRequest("models/model1.3ds"));
mc1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on3dsLoad);

var mc2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
mc2.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
mc2.load(new URLRequest("models/model2.3ds"));
mc2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on3dsLoad);
mc2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on3dsLoad);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

can be so?

```
var mc:Array = [];
for(var i:int=0; i<2;i++){
   getMC("models/model"+(i+1)+".3ds",mc[i]); 
}
function getMC(url:String,ret:Object):void{
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
   loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;  
   lodaer.load(new URLRequest());  
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on3dsLoad);
   function on3dsLoad(e:Event):void{
      ret = e.target
   }
}
```

but how to choose the desired object and assign it a value x,y,?